# Meaning fo this. How utterly “Rob Thomas” of me!

Tags: meaning

There are this dialogue in Drama, Psych season 8.
I know Curt smith and Rob Thomas are singer by googling. By the way, what is the meaning of the bold part?

> Curt Smith: Guster, what a surprise! You caught me listening to my own music. **How utterly “Rob Thomas” of me!**

Answer (score 3):

Generally the structure means that what you did/said is strongly reminding of the mentioned person. In this case listening to his own music is something he immediately associates with Rob Thomas.